# How does entity framework optimize linq queries

Tags: linq, entity-framework, azure

I am using Azure Mobile Web Services with an Entity Framework Database and am wondering about how to structure my linq query. I have a UserSetting and a User table, with UserSetting being a one-to-many with User. However, since I don't have referential constraints, I don't have a UserId property to query against in linq. So, I'd like to, in one operation, get the UserId and get all UserSettings belonging to the user. Also, I'm posting here because I'm having a hard time figuring out break points on a Web Service when a query is run so I can look at the SQL

So, my question is are these two queries the same thing?

```
    return Query().Where(setting => setting.User.AccountId == currentUser.Id);
    return from setting in Query()
            let user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(user => user.AccountId == currentUser.Id)
            where setting.User == user 
            select setting;
```

Comment: do you have access to `SQL Profiler` on your Database?

Comment: For all intents and purposes they're the same. When you do a query in the second form, behind the scenes it's actually in the first form.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I'm trying to figure out how to get to it. I'm interested to see whether the first query produces a SQL using joins or a subquery to get the user first.